# Restricting string literals to Text only

Tags: haskell, ghc, string-literals, overloaded-strings

I'm aware that the `OverloadedStrings` language pragma wraps an implicit `fromString` around all string literals. What I'd like to do is not actually *overload* strings, but merely change their meaning so that they are *always* turned into `Text`, and therefore, using a string literal as a list of characters should result in a type error.

It appears to be impossible to import the `IsString` class without also importing the `String` instance for that class. Does ghc provide some way for me to restrict string literals to `Text` only?

Comment: To be clear: manually wrapping all string literals in a function `asText :: Text -> Text; asText = id` is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Note that unless you have atypically gargantuan literals, then Text might not be any more efficient than String. Text really shines when you are getting strings from IO.

Comment: See this haskell-cafe [thread](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2012-April/022270.html)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's a little bit of overkill, but one solution is to combine [`OverloadedStrings`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/overloaded_strings.html) and [`RebindableSyntax`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/rebindable_syntax.html).  The `RebindableSyntax` extension causes all the implicit function calls that Haskell syntax uses to refer to whatever functions are in scope; for instance, integer literals use any `fromIntegral`, not necessarily `Prelude.fromIntegral`.  As a side effect, `Prelude` is no longer implicitly imported, so you have to do that manually.  As long as you *do* import it, there shouldn't be any issues with syntax using the wrong function implicitly (I think—I haven't actually used this technique).  When combined with `OverloadedStrings`, this causes `"foo"` to be transformed into `fromString "foo"` for whatever `fromString`'s in scope, not necessarily `Data.String.fromString "foo"`.  So making `fromString` synonymous with `pack` will do what you want.  A complete example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, RebindableSyntax #-}
import Prelude

import qualified Data.Text    as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

fromString :: String -> T.Text
fromString = T.pack

main :: IO ()
main = T.putStrLn "Hello, world!"
```

This works fine, and changing `main` to `main = putStrLn "Hello, world!"` produces the desired error:

```
TestStrings.hs:11:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `String' with actual type `T.Text'
    Expected type: [Char] -> String
      Actual type: String -> T.Text
    In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely `"Hello, world!"'
    In the expression: putStrLn "Hello, world!"
```

Commenting out the definition of `fromString` causes a different error:

```
TestStrings.hs:11:19:
    Not in scope: `fromString'
    Perhaps you meant `showString' (imported from Prelude)
```

If you want it to work with both strict and lazy text, you could define your own `IsString` type class, and make both of them instances; the class doesn't have to be called `IsString`, just so long as it has a `fromString` method.

Also, a word of warning: the section of the GHC manual on `RebindableSyntax` doesn't mention the `fromString` function, and the section on `OverloadedStrings` doesn't mention `RebindableSyntax`.  There's no reason this *shouldn't* work, but I think that means that this solution technically relies on undocumented behavior.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of that. It *is* a bit overkill, but the reason I have for doing this is the same flavor of overkill, so it's all good.

Comment: Does the `T.pack`ing happen at compile time or runtime?

Comment: @CetinSert: The core (with -O or -O2) is `main2 = Data.Text.unpackCString# "Hello, world!"`, so at least it doesn't seem to go via `String` at runtime.

Comment: The missing documentation is a bug, feel free to improve the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

Not a way to achieve this now, but maybe eventually, is the `instance force` as proposed in a [GHC feature proposal under discussion](https://github.com/nomeata/ghc-proposals/blob/patch-1/proposals/0000-forced-class-instantiation.rst), where you’d say

```
instance force IsString Text
```

in your module. This is one of the main motivating examples for the proposal.