# How to show strings in custom Prelude library Protolude

Tags: haskell, prelude.ls

I read [this](http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/protolude.html) blog post on how to create a custom Prelude library. The library can be found [here](https://github.com/sdiehl/protolude). One of the things it does is prohibit `String`. It also defines a function for automatic string conversions ([here](https://github.com/sdiehl/protolude/blob/master/src/Conv.hs)). I have enabled `OverloadedStrings` in the cabal file.

Before using this library I had:

```
data Point = Point Int Int
instance Show Point where
  show (Point x y) = "(" ++ show x ++ ", " ++ show y ++ ")"
```

After using the library it says: "`show' is not a (visible) method of class`Show'"

So I resorted to create a custom function to show the data type:

```
showPoint :: Point -> LText
showPoint (Point x y) = toS ("(" ++ show x ++ ", " ++ show y ++ ")")
```

The compiler is saying that the use of `toS, "(", show` is ambiguous, but I don't understand why. Do I have to do something like what is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552764/restricting-string-literals-to-text-only)?

**Edit:**

Had to disable OverloadedStrings and change the code to the following:

```
showPoint :: Point -> LText
showPoint (Point x y) = toS "(" <> show x <> toS ", " <> show y <> toS ")"
```

Wondering if it is possible to do the same without disabling OverloadedStrings so I don't have to use `toS` for every `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Test where

import Protolude
import qualified Base as PBase

data P = P Int

instance PBase.Show P where
  show (P x) = "a P " ++ show x
```

**Update**

The protolude implemention of `show` is as a normal function (see the end of Protolude.hs):

```
show :: (Show a, StringConv String b) => a -> b
show x = toS (PBase.show x)
```

So you need a `PBase.Show` instance in order use protolude's show function.

Also protolude's `show` can return any of the string types, so you're not forcing others to use of String by defining a PBase.show instance.

**Update #2**

You can import the typeclass `show` function from `GHC.Show`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

import Protolude
import GHC.Show

data P  = P Int

instance Show P where
  show (P x) = "<-- P " ++ GHC.Show.show x ++ " -->"

main = print (P 123)
```

Comment: But wouldn't that defeat the purpose of hiding Show? Or I am just misinterpreting the use of Protolude library? That would be returning a `String`, if I am not mistaken, so it would reintroduce the hidden type that the library wanted to avoid.

Comment: So the return type of `show` is inferred to `LText`? How does `show` interact with the SPECIALIZE pragmas?

Comment: The return type of `PBase.show` is always `String`. The return type of protolude's show can be Text or LText or String or any other type `b` for which `StringConv String b` holds. SPECIALIZE just tells GHC to create monomorphic implementations of the function for certain types. This can make those routines run faster - otherwise the polymorphic code is executed.

Comment: Do you have to do anything special to import `import qualified Base as PBase` ? It says it is a hidden module in the package protolude.

Comment: Your solution would resolve to `String`, right? Is it possible to force `show` function from `Show Instance` to always resolve to LText, or Bytestring without passing through `String` ?

Comment: The PBase.show typeclass function _always_ returns a String. But when you call Protolude's  `show` you can specify what the return type should be. The definition of Protolude's `show` is fixed - you cannot change the way it works. It always will call the value's Pbase `show` function and convert the String to whatever result type is requested.

Comment: Just curious, do you think that is a performance efficient implementation? that is one of the expectations I had behind using Protolude and its removal of String.

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused by the following:

- `show` can produce any string-like type
- string literals are overloaded, so they are of any string-like type
- `toS` can accept many different types

If so, the compiler does not know which intermediate string-like type to pick, and an ambiguity error is thrown.

Comment: Is it possible to make the strings literals infer the type `LText`? Do I have to remove the Overloaded strings extension?

Comment: If you mean `toS (("(" :: LText) ++ show x ++ (", " :: LText) ++ show y ++ (")" :: LText))`, then the compiler is still thinking that "..." has type [a].

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion Uhm.. please post the full error. Only one annotation should be enough (the others are then inferred). Which is the type of the `show` you are using, by the way?

Comment: I solved it. Was my fault. Thought (++) was also available with `Text`.

Comment: Tried this: `toS ("My Sample Text" :: LText)` but I get this error: No instance for (StringConv a0 LText) arising from a use of `toS'

   The type variable `a0' is ambiguous

   Note: there are several potential instances:
     ...
   In the expression: toS "My Sample Text"