# How to set preference for `Text` and not `String` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I run often in the problem that GHC interprets `"some text"` as `String` when I need `Text` in places where both are acceptable, only to find later the error in another use and forcing an explicit type annotation.

Is there a way to set a preference for GHC to prefer `Text` and not `String`? The question is likely  [the same as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552764/restricting-string-literals-to-text-only) but the only answer there is very heavy and not likely usable for me. Is there a better one?

I would like to be able to set a preference, that unqualified `"some text"` is of type `Text` to avoid the error in the following contrived example:

```
import Data.Text

some = "some"
text1 = "text1":: Text 

two = Data.Text.concat [some, text1]
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way around `RebindableSyntax`. You need `OverloadedStrings` to make string literals able to be used as anything other than `String` **at all**, but then you need `RebindableSyntax` to make them desugar to something other than calls to the builtin `fromString` (and the builtin `fromString` supports returning `String`). If that's the answer this is a duplicate question, really; hopefully someone else has something clever though.

Comment: The issue you're describing isn't in the example you gave. You just forgot to enable `OverloadedStrings`. I've answered based on the issue you described in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put a `default` declaration at the top of the module so that `Text` will be defaulted for any ambiguous `IsString` values.

```
default (Integer, Double, Text)
```

In your code, the type is not ambiguous because you specified a `Text`-only function. The error just results from not enabling `OverloadedStrings`. Here is a truly ambiguous example that would benefit from a `default` declaration.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text

default (Integer, Double, Text)

some = "some"

main = print some
```

Inspecting this in GHCi shows that `:t some` is `Text`. Without the `default` declaration, `:t some` is `[Char]` (i.e. `String`).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and did not find in the docs... (I have `OverloadedStrings` enabled and forgot to show it in the question; thank you for spotting it!)

Answer (score 0):

Just enable the `OverloadedStrings` extension, this can be done by adding `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` to the top of the file.

This will automatically choose the appropriate 'string' type.

Comment: Maybe we need some clarification, but I think the OP was already using `OverloadedStrings`. Without that extension, there is never any ambiguity; GHC will simply always interpret `"quoted-strings"` as expressions of type `String`. There's no choice that one could have a preference about which way to resolve, and adding an explicit type annotation will not change anything (you need to actually call a conversion function like `pack`). Also the OP links to another question where the starting point is `OverloadedStrings` already being in use.